# Transition ease not working on hover when using Bootstrap 4 classes together

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, ui-design

Using angular js and bootstrap - And the on-hover when the div's height is increasing, transition ease is not working.

```
<div class="sidebar-list-item customHeight"><a ui-sref-active="active" ui-sref="home.dashboard.usermaster" class="sidebar-link text-muted"><span>Products</span></a>
      <ul class="sidebar-menu list-unstyled border-left border-primary border-thick">
        <li ng-repeat="product in prod" class="sidebar-list-item"><a ng-click="ctrl.getProduct(product)" class="sidebar-link text-muted pl-lg-3">{{product}}</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

customHeight class

```
.customHeight {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 52px;
  transition: height .5s ease-in-out 0.5s;
}
.customHeight:hover {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;
}
```

Transition ease is not working with height: auto.

Comment: Im aware the linked question is about `height:0` => `height:auto` but its the very same problem youre facing with `height:52px` => `height:auto`

Comment: < transition: height .5s ease-in-out 0.5s > this line in css is not working.

Comment: Please refer to the possible duplicate i linked, a solution is described there. TL;DR: you cant transition to non-absolute values like `height:auto` using css only.

Comment: Yes you are right transition ease is not working on height:auto. Give some solution for that as I am using ng-repeat to display the list so the height varies with the list size. So I can't keep the height as static.

Comment: As i already stated twice, please refer to the possible duplicate question that i linked in my first comment. A proper answer to your question (for css only) is provided there.

Comment: Ya ! I saw that, it resolved my issue. shall I delete the question??

Comment: No, its now officially markes as duplicate, so everybody who finds your question does find the proper solution. No need to delete the question at all.